# Something wrong with array

Tags: php, arrays, replace

I'm using this code to get first number and replace it with 0-9, but I always get 0-0-9 result. Then I deleted in array 9 it started to work correct. why it works that way ?

```
$direction = strtoupper(substr($query_row["Band"],0,1));

$replace = [
'0' => '0-9','1' => '0-9','2' => '0-9','3' => '0-9','4' => '0-9',
'5' => '0-9','6' => '0-9','7' => '0-9','8' => '0-9', '9' => '0-9' ];

$dir= str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $direction);
```

Comment: Remove **,**  start in array

Comment: Typo `$replace = [
,'0'`

Comment: i understood your problem why it is happening
as you replace `0 => 0-9` and then `9 => 0-9` which means 0 becomec 0-0-9
Searching for a solution please wait

Comment: I think you have a problem with multiple numbers in `$direction`. If you have more than 1 number it will replace all of these, not only the first one. Please give an example for `$direction` and an expected result.

Comment: Post the value of `$direction` too. Along with expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
$search = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8');
$replace = array('0-9','0-9','0-9','0-9','0-9','0-9','0-9','0-9','0-9');
$dir = str_replace($search, $replace, $direction);
```

and then work around for 9 which depends on your string
mine was `0123456789` so I tried
`$dir = str_replace('99', '9,0-9', $dir);`

its working on mine

Comment: Thank you, you set me on the way to fing out the solution. I changed   fist $dir to $direct   $dir = str_replace('99', '9,0-9', $dir);    to   $dir = str_replace('0-9-9', '0-9', $direct); :)

Answer (score 1):

It's explained in the documentation of [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

> **Caution**
>
> #### Replacement order gotcha
>
> Because `str_replace()` replaces left to right, it might replace a previously inserted value when doing multiple replacements.

You pass arrays as first two arguments to `str_replace()`. This is the same as you would call `str_replace()` repeatedly for each element in the array.

If `$direction` is not `'9'` then it replaces it with `'0-9'`. Then, on the last cycle it replaces `'9'` from `'0-9'` with `'0-9'` (according to the values you passed it).

---

I would drop the code after the first line and read the first sentence again: *"get first number and replace it with 0-9"*.

If your goal is to get the first character of `$query_row["Band"]` and replace it with `0-9` if it is a digit (and make it uppercase otherwise) I would write something more simple:

```
$direction = substr($query_row["Band"], 0, 1);

if (is_numeric($direction)) {
    $dir = '0-9';
} else {
    $dir = strtoupper($direction);
}
```